# How to create new columns in a python DataFrame using .format

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list codes[ ] whose elements are random integears which are supposed to be column headings of a new DataFrame.

```
for i in range (len(codes)):
       df['col{}'.format(codes[i])]
```

Gives me: 
KeyError: 'col1'

Can anybody please tell me if there's any way to rectify this or tell me about another way to convert these list elements to new columns ?

Comment: This `df.columns = ['col{}'.format(i) for i in codes]`?

Answer (score 0):

You can always set new column names when instantiating the dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["col{}".format(_code) for _code in codes])
```

Answer (score 0):

Or use `map` with `__add__`:

```
df.columns = map('col'.__add__, codes)
```

Or use `map` with `format`:

```
df.columns = map('col{}'.format, codes)
```